# How can I modify/adjust the size of a contact form?

Tags: html, css, contact-form

I just learned to create a contact form to place on my webpage.
I used an html and css code from w3 schools as a template and used that to create the contact form of my webpage.
But when I checked it on a browser, the entire container expands all the way to the end of the page.
I've been looking up ways to adjust the size of the container so that it only fills up half the lower section of my webpage.
I would appreciate some input on about this. Thank you.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h3>Contact Form</h3>

  <div class="container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
      </select>

      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Good start. My comment is not directly related to solving your stated question, but gives you something to consider for your entire design future. You should investigate how to accomplish your goal using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) - learning those techniques early will help you solve ANY page layout problem you run into in the future.

Comment: Do you want to be half horizontal?

Comment: Better show the desired result with a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

I just added `width:50%` to your container class.

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
```

```html
<body>

<h3>Contact Form</h3>

<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

    <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

    <label for="country">Country</label>
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no, he is looking for height  " only fills up half the lower section of my webpage."

Comment: this "_I've been looking up ways to adjust the size of the container so that it only fills up half the lower section_"

Comment: "Half the lower section" can be interpreted differently depending on how it's read. - Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Hi guys. Sorry for replying late. Thank you for your help. It was indeed the container width that I should have changed. I added a width value of 50% for the container and the entire message box finally gave a horizontal display of half the webpage.

Comment: So my original answer was correct before the edit was made? - lol. Glad to help man.

Answer (score 0):

hi if you want the container "only fills up half the lower section of my webpage"
you need to create a html tag that has diplay of block like div and name it what ever class you want for eample let say you call it like this:

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
... ..
..
..
```

then in css you can style this tag like this

```
.foo{
width:100%;
height:50vh;
}
```

that "vh" standt for vertical height
it means who ever visit this page, and what ever their screen size is,
I want this div have in 50% of their height
and if you run this snippet full size you will see what i mean

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
        body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
    
        * {box-sizing: border-box;}
    
    
     .foo{
        width:100%;
        height:50vh;
        }
    
        input[type=text], select, textarea {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          border-radius: 4px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          margin-top: 6px;
          margin-bottom: 16px;
          resize: vertical;
        }
    
        input[type=submit] {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
          padding: 12px 20px;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 4px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
    
        input[type=submit]:hover {
          background-color: #45a049;
        }
    
        .container {
          border-radius: 5px;
          background-color: #f2f2f2;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
```

```html
<body>
    
        <h3>Contact Form</h3>
        <div class="foo"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
    
            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">
    
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select id="country" name="country">
              <option value="australia">Australia</option>
              <option value="canada">Canada</option>
              <option value="usa">USA</option>
            </select>
    
            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
            <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>
    
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
        </div>
    
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved `<h3>` tag to the `.container` div and set new style for `.container` and give the `.contaner`'s style to `<form>` tag and... review the below snippet code

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=text],
select,
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container h3 {
  width: 320px;
}

form {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 320px;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="container">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

      <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="usa">USA</option>
      </select>

      <label for="subject">Subject</label>
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestion. I had just changed the .container div to 50% and it worked.